# css columns not showing correctly in ie9 and ie8

Tags: internet-explorer, cross-browser

Does anyone know how to make the css3 columns work in ie8 and 9? Instead of three columns appearing, there's only one list. Any help, much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Internet Explorer 8 and 9 did not support CSS Columns. It wasn't [until version 10](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh772211%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) that Microsoft first added this support, lacking a prefix, into the Browser. As a result, you won't be able to get native CSS Column support in prior versions of Internet Explorer.

The best solution you may have is to conditionally load [a plugin](https://github.com/adamwulf/Columnizer-jQuery-Plugin) that can achieve similar functionality for you in legacy browsers. Consider the following:

```html
<style>
    #columns {
        -webkit-column-width: 200px;
        -moz-column-width: 200px;
        column-width: 200px;
    }
</style>
<!--[if lte IE 9 ]>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function () {
        $('#columns').columnize({ width: 200 });
    });
</script>
<![endif]-->
```

In this case, Internet Explorer 10+ and other modern browsers will use the CSS approach. Internet Explorer 9 and below will use a jQuery alternative.

Be sure to use the 1.x branch of jQuery as the 2.x branch will not support older versions of IE.